# Matching 1 number with another from a table, and then Getting a Name

Tags: sql, dialogflow-es

I'm not an expert on SQL and at this point, I don't know if my code is written in a correct way.

The result that I'm looking for is this...

If you insert a number, that number is going to be checked and tried to match with another number in the Database, and then if the number is equal I want to get the name from the numbers's row.

I will insert my id or wherever number and the system is going to check if that number exist and then the system is going to show me my name**

This is my code...[Php to dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wetV.png)

The code squared in yellow is the SLQ...

DB is connected successfully.
If the recived_intent(intention from dialogflow) is read_id

$patient_name is equal to the function query_patient_name(of $idPatient... which is the data that dialogflow is getting)
[dialogflow getting correctly the parameters...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDRux.png)

then we declare result as a query when we are going to

```
select `fname` (column) FROM `patient_data` (table) WHERE `ss` (column) is equal to the $idPatient.
```

[PhpMyAdmin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klzF2.png)

Then we get the value with mysqli_fetch_assoc and finally we get in return the wonderful name.

I've been reading on the Internet without luck, so I decided to ask you guys.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
function consulta_nombre_paciente( $idPatient )
{
    global $mysqli;

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT fname FROM patient_data WHERE ss = $idPatient");               

    if ($result)
    {       
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())          
        {
            return $row["fname"];       
        }
        else
        {
            //no match                      
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        echo $mysqli->error;            
    }
    return null;
}
```

if there is no matching or an error, the code will return `null`

Comment: I've tryed with no results, But Thanks a lot Draz, Do you know if there is a way to at least match the number from the table with the number inserted?

Comment: probably the number you try to match is not in the table yet.
try to insert a new row into the database table with the number you are looking for.
this should definitely work!

Comment: Draz, actually I tryed verifying what information comes to dialogflow. I found that the problem is the sql sentence... Do you know whats the correct way to write it? I'm not getting the value...

Comment: This is The tense ( select `fname`  FROM `patient_data`  WHERE `ss` LIKE $idPatient. I think.. this isn't the correct way to get it but when I put the tense on mysql I get the result I'm Looking for.